# IOS: Custom real time audio effect for audioEngine?

Tags: ios, signal-processing, audiounit

What is best way for creating custom real time audio effect for audioEngine in iOS ?
I want to process audio at a low level, how to do it right? Be sure to use AudioUnitExtension? By simpler, I meant, is it possible to inherit from Audio Unit and using C code to change audio Data and send it back to the audioUnit connection chain in audioEngine?

Comment: It seems like you want to do low level custom audio processing, but at the same time don't want the hassle.  Low-level = hassle; there's now way around it.  I'm voting to close because I think you need to decide what you want, and we can't tell you the answer to that.  (Or, I'd suggest, edit your question so it's clear what you're asking.)

Comment: I added a description, but I still need to understand how to process audio at a low level. I do not understand how to do this to connect to audioEngine.

Comment: For example, I would like custom AudioUnit add speex code for Echo Cancellation. Can this be done through AudioUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the framework AudioKit will let you do what you want, the problem with manipulating audio at a low level is you have to deal with a lot of complex stuff tangental to what you are trying to achieve, just changing the playback rate of a sample means you have to deal with interpolation and antialias filters, AudioKit handles all of that for you but it may mean you have to change your way of thinking about what you are trying to.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit

Comment: I tried audioKit, and there is no what I need, for example Echo Cancellation.